# How to make scrollable vertical grid of images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to make list of images which is scrollable along vertical axis.

Images' links are in `string[] imagesLocation`.

When tile is clicked, event handler should know `string imageLocation`.

It shoul look something like this:

[image]

I was able to make it in grid. But couldn't make it scrollable.

Found some tip to use `LongListSelector`, but couldn't make it to work.

**Update:**

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ContentPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            ContentPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength() });
            ContentPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength() });
            ContentPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { });
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    Image MyImage1 = new Image();
                    MyImage1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);
                    MyImage1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, j);

                    ImageSource src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format("Assets/ApplicationIcon.png"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                    MyImage1.Source = src;

                    ContentPanel.Children.Add(MyImage1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MailPage.xaml:**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentPanel">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Have you tried gridview?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of an easy solution which you could try. 
Insert a `Panel` first and then create the grid inside the `panel`

The `panel` has a property called `AutoScroll` You just have to set that to `True`

```
    panel.AutoScroll = "True";
```

`WrapPanel` is great for laying out things in a vertical or horizontal orientation until you reach the edge of the container and then move to the next column or row. But unfortunately I found `WrapPanel` is no longer supported by Windows Store apps (Universal Apps).

`UniversalWrapPanel` is an alternative for `WrapPanel` layout.

This is considering you're working on `Visual Studio`

To get the `UniversalWrapPanel`, go to the package manager, find and install Package `UniversalWrapPanel` This will add the DLL in your references.

Then Open `MainPage.xaml` and add the namespace to the XAML:

```
xmlns:UniversalWrapPanel="using:Gregstoll"
```

Comment: Cannot insert `Panel`: `Panel is abstract and must include implicit value`

Comment: cannot make it work. Firstly I tried `WrapPanel`, installed WPToolKit. Secondly `UniversalWrapPanel`, cannot install the package from nugget, package does not contain assemblies for v8.1